# Need to update field immediately when date is today

Tags: workflow, process-builder, time-dependent-workflow

**Requirement** : I have Date field FollowUp date and when the date is today I need to update the field.

**Sol**: I have created a Time dependent Workflow and set the 1 Hr after the FollowUp date.
But I need to update it immediately when the date is reached.
If I edit the record and set date  as today then it needs to  update the field immediately.
How can I Achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use "0 hours after" instead?

Comment: It's worked for me before that way.