# Workflow to update fields based on Date field

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have one Date field follow-up date if date is today then I am updating fields.
So I created time dependent workflow and if date is future date then it will update a field on that date
1hr After follow-up date. 
But I need to update a field immediately instead of 1 hr
How can I achieve this.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141458/need-to-update-field-immediately-when-date-is-today

Answer (score 0):

Hey @ajay bagdad As per understood your requirement.you can do it while creating your time trigger.

For reference: i am attaching image.

[image]

I think it resolves your issue.